# Creating synonyms for two tags with similar counts - but chosing the master to be the one with the lower count

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

Somewhat related to the [We have tons of synonyms, now what?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58751/we-have-tons-of-synonyms-now-what) question.

Minor nitpick on the synonym proposal UI. The master seems to always the one with the "highest" number of occurrences. However, when the numbers are pretty similar (within a factor of X, (X ~= 30% or something)), perhaps either one should be allowed to be the master.

The specific case I'm looking at is [emacs-lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emacs-lisp) and [elisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elisp), which each have 246 and 277 questions (respectively).

According to the massive response to the [retag request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31498/possible-tag-merge-elisp-emacs-lisp) for these tags (7 votes among 3 answers), `emacs-lisp` was the winner. Yet that tag currently cannot be named the master because it has fewer votes.

Should the threshold be changed to take into account numbers of tags that are within a certain (small) constant factor?

Comment: +1, but I still prefer elisp. By the way, when you say that each tag has xxx votes (3rd paragraph), do you mean each tag has xxx uses, or a count of xxx? The way you put it is a bit confusing, as I was thinking you meant people voted that tag as the best of the two.

Comment: @Vivi Yah, I just updated the vote->questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, when the numbers are pretty similar (within a factor of X, (X ~= 30% or something)), perhaps either one should be allowed to be the master.

For some time, this has been the way it works, where X = 20%.

Answer (score 0):

> Should the threshold be changed to
>   take into account numbers of tags that
>   are within a certain (small) constant
>   factor?

Nope I do not think it should, in cases like this it needs to be discussed on meta and appropriately retagged. In fact I would go as far as to say that it should be disallowed if there are 20%-30% less on either side.

Keep in mind the original retag request was never completed, so as it stands no decision has been made, there are 3 votes one way, and 1 vote the other.

In all cases where there are a hundred tags on each side, the moderators are going to have to step in and do a mass merge anyway.

Comment: Isn't the purpose of the synonym system to use the community to merge tags?  i.e. Why do we need both a discussion on meta, *and* to use the synonym system?  Do you really expect a lot of discussion on meta around two tags that each have less than 300 questions?